# Band of color around a light source

Tags: visible-light

When a light source, like a phone flash light, is observed in the dark, why is there a band of seven colors observed as a ring around it ?

Comment: Experiment suggests that not all light sources seen at night show this effect, so there must be some other factor in play. Was if misty when you saw the coloured band? If not, maybe there's something in the design of you phone flashlight that is diffracting the light.

Comment: Too many unknowns: what lens on what light source, how are you viewing it, and so on.